# Building dynamic SQL queries with psycopg2 and postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm not really sure the best way to go about this or if i'm just asking for a life that's easier than it should be. I have a backend for a web application and I like to write all of the queries in raw SQL. For instance getting a specific user profile, or a number of users I have a query like this:

```
SELECT accounts.id,
    accounts.username,
    accounts.is_brony,
WHERE accounts.id IN %(ids)s;
```

This is really nice because I can get one user profile, or many user profiles with the same query. Now my real query is actually almost 50 lines long. It has a lot of joins and other conditions for this profile.

Lets say I want to get all of the same information from a user profile but instead of getting a specific user ID i want to get a single random user? I don't think it makes sense to copy and paste 50 lines of code just to modify two lines at the end.

```
SELECT accounts.id,
    accounts.username,
    accounts.is_brony,
ORDER BY Random()
LIMIT 1;
```

Is there some way to use some sort of inheritance in building queries, so that at the end I can modify a couple of conditions while keeping the core similarities the same?

I'm sure I could manage it by concatenating strings and such, but I was curious if there's a more widely accepted method for approaching such a situation. Google has failed me.

Comment: Subqueries? Something like `select * from (<core query here>) as t order by random() limit 1;`

Comment: that makes sense. is the any big performance impact with sticking a query into a subquery? I try to test it myself when i get a bit of time.

Comment: It is depending on the "core query" and query planner.

Comment: I'll run both through postgres explain and see what it spits out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical answer is to create a view and use that with different `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses in queries.

But, depending on your query and your tables, that might not be a good solution for your special case.

A query that is blazingly fast with `WHERE accounts.id IN (1, 2, 3)` might perform abysmally with `ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1`. In that case you'll have to come up with a different query for the second requirement.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I've essentially done now. I will just have to test the outcomes with large sets of dummy data to make sure there will be no future performance concerns.